# Apply a loadmask to Viewport that also covers floating Components

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

How can I add a loadmask within the **launch** method of the Ext.applcation to the **viewport** that will also covers **floating components** like windows when get showed?

Currently the mask work but does not cover any opened window.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer [here](http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?15882-CLOSED-Mask-not-covering-the-modal-window), the trick is to increase the z-order of the mask:

```
Ext.getBody().mask().dom.style.zIndex = '99999';
```

I made a test, it works for me.

Comment: This seems to be what I am looking for. Only the solution seems a bit dirty... But I will give it a try

Comment: Yes this seems to work but I guess I asked it wrong. I need a loadmask. but I will give you +1 because it work and you waited long for this reply ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom loader that will hide itself when everything is loaded...

1.Create html holder in body:

```
<div id="loading-mask"></div>
<div id="loading">
   <span id="loading-message">Loading. Please wait...</span>
</div>
```

2.  Add css to properly position mask:

```
#loading-mask {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #ffffff;
    z-index: 1;
}
#loading {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 45%;
    z-index: 2;
    font-family: tahoma,arial,verdana,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
#loading span {
    padding: 5px 30px;
    display: block;
}
```

3. Create js function outside Ext.onReady call:

```
function hidePreloader() {
    var loadingMask = Ext.get('loading-mask');
    var loading = Ext.get('loading');

    //  Hide loading message            
    loading.fadeOut({ duration: 0.2, remove: true });

    //  Hide loading mask
    loadingMask.setOpacity(0.9);
    loadingMask.shift({
        xy: loading.getXY(),
        width: loading.getWidth(),
        height: loading.getHeight(),
        remove: true,
        duration: 1,
        opacity: 0.1,
        easing: 'bounceOut'
    });
 }
```

4. Call hidePreloader method when all components and tasks are completed and ready, in your case after app.js launch method is fininshed loading, for example:

```
listeners: {
    afterrender: function(form) {
        hidePreloader();
    }
}
```

### here is a [example](http://jsfiddle.net/rqgJN/) in fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Even this is not what I am exactly asking for it is something that I definitely need so got my +1 But the example ends in a 404

Answer (score 1):

I preferred my solution with CSS:

```
body.x-masked .x-mask {
    z-index: 20000;
}
```

since window z-index is 19001, so 20000 is not bad.